# How can you show a modal in react when you press the back button browser?

Tags: reactjs, browser-history

I need to show a modal when user wants to leave a specified page. 
When User wants to go on a different link from the page, I solve this with `getUserConfirmation` like that:

```
const getUserConfirmation = (message, callback) => {
const history = createBrowserHistory({
     forceRefresh: true
     })

 if (history.location.pathname == "/add/car") {
     store.dispatch(showModal('ConfirmationLeavingAddPageModal', { callback }));
 }
 }
```

The problem is when I press the back button on browser it doesn't work anymore.
Any Help Accepted?

Comment: i don't think you can create events on browser back button but you need to handle the redirection in order to achieve what you want

Answer (score 1):

For `react-router` 2.4.0+

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.router.setRouteLeaveHook(this.props.route, () => {
        if (history.location.pathname == "/add/car") {
            store.dispatch(showModal('ConfirmationLeavingAddPageModal', {
                callback
            }));
        }
    })
}
```

in addition you need to `import { withRouter } from 'react-router'` and `export default withRouter(YourComponent)`